# Limit \renewcommand{\chaptername}{} for one part only

Tags: chapters

I'm currently compiling a manual in LaTeX and the manual has 3 parts. For part 1 the chapters are called core, for part 2 the chapters are called QI and for part 3 the chapters are called GP. I want the chapters to look like the photo I attached.

[image: what I want the chapters to look like]

I'm currently using `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}` but it also applies that the chapters for Part 2 are called core but I want the chapters for part 2 and part 3 to be different from each other as well.

What command can I use?

Comment: Welcome ! See `package{titlesec}` and provide us a MWE (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: You could use \let\oldchaptername\chaptername before the \renewcommand... , and before the next chapter \renewcommand\chaptername\oldchaptername .

Comment: Can't you use `\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}` multiple times in your document?

Comment: Try `\documentclass{book}
\let\oldchaptername\chaptername
\begin{document}
\part{Some part}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\chapter{A chapter without name}
\chapter{Another chapter without name}
\part{Some other part}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\oldchaptername}
\chapter{A chapter with name}
\chapter{Another chapter with name}
\end{document}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define the names at the beginning, based on the value of the `part` counter.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % to get a small image

\renewcommand{\chaptername}{%
  \ifcase\value{part}%
    Chapter\or % 0
    Core\or    % 1
    QI\or      % 2
    GP\else    % 3
    Chapter    % else
  \fi
}
\counterwithin*{chapter}{part}

\begin{document}

\part{Core}
\chapter{Test}

\part{QI}
\chapter{Test}

\part{GP}
\chapter{Test}

\clearpage
\mbox{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for sharing this. It's exactly how I want it to go. I'm currently having a problem with \counterwithin it seems to have an error

Comment: @Maris Try and see if adding `\usepackage{chngcntr}` solves the issue.

Comment: Works perfectly now!!! Thank you!!!